# WIreless USB mouse does't work when laptop is on battery

Tags: usb, mouse, power-management, battery

I have a problem with my wireless USB mouse while working on battery. When laptop is plugged into power source mouse works pretty well.

The problem started after I run some script that aimed to tune up laptops' power consumption.

So I think that the script decreased the voltage of the USB ports while working on battery and I don't know how to revert that.

Can anyone help me solve this? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: If you run Ubuntu off a live CD image, does it work? If so it could be what you changed — what modifications did you install?

Answer (score 1):

Your USB is most probably going into autosuspend. Did you install TLP by any chance? If so, edit the configuration file using -

`sudo gedit /etc/default/tlp`

and change USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1 to USB_AUTOSUSPEND=0.

Alternatively, if TLP isn't installed, to blacklist devices that are not working with USB autosuspend and enable it for all other devices -

`sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/50-usb_power_save.rules`

Make the following changes -

```
# blacklist for usb autosuspend
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="05c6", ATTR{idProduct}=="9205", GOTO="power_usb_rules_end"

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto"
LABEL="power_usb_rules_end"
```

where ATTR{idVendor} and ATTR{idProduct} can be found out using `lsusb`